# How can i disable ip binding in Juniper SSL VPN SA-2500?

Tags: juniper

At the moment it is set to allow Admins with specific ip addresses to log into the admin console.
I'd like to allow everyone to open the admin console without checking the machine's ip.
Anyone knows how it is done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is relevant to you anymore but perhaps it can be of use for someone else.

You configure this under the "Administrators" -> "Admin Realms" -> "Admin Users"(or whatever your realm is called) -> the tab "Authentication Policy" and choose the radiobutton that says "Allow users to sign in from any IP address".

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes, this is exactly correct.